# How do we measure the benefit of UXSE for users?

Tags: discussion

Remembering back to the time when I was teaching a UX design course, I used to tell students that UXSE is one of the many different resources that can be used to help with professional development. Not only is it good for gathering insights from the industry professionals from around the world (rather than just within your own country), the simple act of asking AND answering questions is a great exercise in communication and critical thinking.

As it turns out, it took a lot of encouragement (in the form of incentives) to get the students to attempt to post questions (I say attempt because most of them were closed), and eventually all of them gave up.

Given my previous experience with introducing UXSE to new users, I am curious as to how we are measuring the value and impact of UXSE, similar to this question that was asked at Skeptics StackExchange on the [claim about StackOverflow improving productivity of programmers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/18539/has-stack-overflow-saved-billions-of-dollars-in-programmer-productivity). We can see some statistics on our individual profile page regarding how many people we have reached, but are there other things that are more indicative of the direct benefits?